# Machine Learning: How to avoid over-fitting in for small data sets?

Tags: machine-learning, cluster-analysis

If we want to apply machine learning job on a small data set with many attributes, it may be easy to get over-fitting problem. 
How to avoid this?

Comment: Get more data. Seriously, if you have few data and then apply some (complicated) model to it, that's not going to work.

Comment: Thanks for your advice, while I can only get a small set of data.

Comment: Might anyhow be better suited for http://stats.stackexchange.com/  or http://datascience.stackexchange.com/ (but I'm sure that on both sites, a similar question was asked before)

Comment: I agree cross-validated and data science are better forums for this question, but you could look into *regularization*, which adds a term to your objective function which punishes complex curve-fitting solutions. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regularization_%28mathematics%29

Comment: Your question is too broad. There's multiple established things one can do to prevent overfitting. If your training stops too early because you have not enough data then that's a completely different problem, i.e. you don't have enough data.

Comment: Thanks you for pointing out. I found some questions on cross-validated.

Answer (score 1):

The simplest answer is to use over-fitting resistant methods such as random forest or boosting with stump as the weak learner.